# How can I use single or double quote in Clojure Macro?

Tags: clojure

I am making a macro which uses single quotes. However, whenever I parse the macro the single quote text like:

```
'java'
```

:is expanded to:

```
(quote java')
```

Does anyone know a way around this so that it doesn't expand to the quoted form?

### Update

I have a kind of working workaround for this. I use:

```
(map (fn[x]
   (if (.startsWith (str x) "(quote ") 
     (apply str "'" (rest x)) 
     x)
```

: and this at least converts the 'text' to the string "'text'" which works for me

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work and is, I think, semantically equivalent. Can you give an example of your macro, a possible use case and a desired result?

Comment: I am parsing SQL statements so macros like (select id from table where name like '%java%') needs to be parsed

Comment: The Clojure reader is going to make it hard to do this. A macro can't change what `'` does.

Comment: I may have a workaround, by checking each part of the arguments converting it using str. If the argument starts with "(quote " then I know it starts with '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure macros apply to the result of the clojure reader's parsing of the source text. Has two effects:

1. You will only get valid clojure datastructures as arguments to a macro.
2. You can only output one valid clojure datastructure from a macro.

One of the consequences of this is that certain syntactical constructs can not made to work using macros (since they cannot be read) and require a different reader (meaning you cannot mix them into normal clojure source files).

As an example:

```
(`foo`)
```

is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make a string with single quotes wrapping `java`. To do this you need to use a backslash to escape the single quotes.

```
"\'java\'"
```

You were quoting the symbol `java'` which wasn't going to give you what you wanted.

Comment: The backslashes here add nothing. Your suggestion is equivalent to `"'java'"`.